# Convert parent to child

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, inheritance

I have class called `AbsAlgorithm` with three pure virtual functions like this:

```
class AbsAlgorithm
{
public:
    //...other methods
    virtual void run() = 0;
    virtual bool init(TestCase&) = 0;
    virtual void done() = 0;
};
```

This class is in my executable, called `algatorc`. End-user must create algatorc project and must also implement these three methods. But the problem is this: he must also inherit `TestCase` class. which is parameter in `init` method. In my main program, I must compile code that user wrote, and build dynamic library and load it into my program. I did that. The problem is when I call `init` method.

Example:

User creates new algatorc project called `Sorting`.

So he ends up with three classes:

- `SortingTestSetIterator`
- `SortingTestCase`
- `SortingAbsAlgorithm`

In this `SortingAbsAlgorithm` he inherits `AbsAlgorithm` and implements pure virtual methods. In `SortingTestCase` he must inherit `TestCase` class and in `SortingTestSetIterator` he must inherit `TestSetIterator` and implement method called `get_current()`, which returns `TestCase`.

My main program I loaded `SortingTestSetIterator` into `TestSetIterator`, like this:

```
create_it = (TestSetIterator* (*)())dlsym(handle, "create_iterator_object");
TestSetIterator *it = (TestSetIterator*)create_it();
```

So now, I can call methods like `TestSetIterator::get_current()` (this method returns pointer to `TestCase`, but user returns object of SortingTestCase). But when I call this method, as a result, I get `TestCase`. This is all ok, but then I need to pass this to `AbsAlgorithm::init(...)`. Sure, still no problem, but when user implemented method `init(...)`, he must convert this to child class (`SortingTestCase`). Is this possible?

I know that this is trivial in Java, but I don't know how to do this in C++. Or is it a way that I define method `TestCase* TestSetIterator::get_current()` and then user somehow redefine this so that return type is `SortingTestCase`? Would this solve the problem?

Basically, problem is this:

I have method `SortingTestSetIterator::get_current()` that returns pointer to instance of `SortingTestCase` class. So, is it somehow posible to convert parent to child?

Comment: the quick and dirty solution in C++ would be to use a `dynamic_cast` a la `SortingTestCase * sort_case = dynamic_cast<SortingTestCase*>(test_case);` Otherwise you may have to implement some further logic such as the Visitor Pattern to get these classes to communicate with each other.

Comment: `error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘test_case’ (of type ‘class TestCase*’) to type ‘class SortingTestCase*’ (source type is not polymorphic)`
Does this mean that class `TestCase` is not polymorphic? How to make it polymorphic?

Comment: @golobich: in order to be polymorphic, `TestCase` must have at least one virtual function.  It almost certainly needs a virtual destructor, or you'll have problems when you try to clean things up...

Comment: aaaa nightmare...now I have memory leak :D I will fix this leak on my on (but just for the record, which tool to you find most helpful for memory leaks? Valgrind?).
So, this dynamic_cast and virtual method/destructor, helped me solve this issue. If could on of you post answer with content of both yours comment, I will gladly accept it. Thank you.

Comment: I still don't get why you need to downcast to child class when implementing `init()`. Could you update your question with at least some pseudo-code?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos for my BSc I am doing program to test users algorithm. So in `SortingTestCase` there would be probably some array and size of this array. If user create new project for Matrix multiplication, then there would probably be two 2D array and their size ofcourse. Because then in method `run` end user call method `execute` (that he wrote), and pass parameters. for instance `execute(test_case->array, test_case->size);` I don't need to downcast to child if there is an option to call this class members from `TestCase`. Is this clear know? If not I can provide source code

Comment: I think I got it. Unfortunately, it's not possible to do this with C++ (and probably neither with Java as you stated). Child-specific members cannot be accessed from base class because the base is not able to know details of the implementation of its child. Also, this means that you are violating the [LSP](http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to cast Parent to Child, all you need to do is to write this:

```
child = dynamic_cast<Child*>(parent_object)
```

But in order to do so, your source class (Parent class) must have at least one virtual method! It almost certainly needs a virtual destructor, or you'll have problems when you try to clean things up...